# c++ print array contents in reverse with pointer - why does this method work?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

From C++ Early Objects - Gaddis, 8th Edition. I note similar questions on SO, but none that answer this aspect. Consider this simple program:

```
// This program uses a pointer to display
// the contents of an array.
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

int main(){
    const int SIZE = 8;
    int set[ ] = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40};
    int *numPtr;   // Pointer   

    // Make numPtr point to the set array.
    numPtr = set;

    // Use the pointer to display the array elements
    cout << "The numbers in set are:\n";
    for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++) {
        cout << *numPtr << " ";
        numPtr++;
    }

    // Display the array elements in reverse order
    cout << "\nThe numbers in set backwards are:\n";
    for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++) {
        numPtr--;
        cout << *numPtr << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Works, I tested it! But conceptually, numPtr is pointing to the starting address of the array "set", so how does incrementing numPtr "backwards" from the starting address not cause a segfault on the first iteration of the second (reversing) for loop? Restating the question, how is numPtr "knowing" to begin at the address of the last element of the array "set"?
Be gentle, I'm in Intro to CS II... thanks!

Comment: Hint: what does `numPtr++` do to `numPtr`?

Comment: Building on juanchopanza's hint, you have to consider the code *as a whole*. `numPtr` is, as you know, a pointer, and its value can change throughout execution. Think through the logic of the code, and see if you can figure out how it changes.

Comment: Cody, thanks, got it, now I'm trying to see how to iterate an array backwards without doing the first loop.  Seems a bit of pointer arithmetic as @Shitsu notes,  set+sizeof(set)-1 would do the trick.

Comment: The first loop effectively does numPtr += SIZE ,,.  so that's what you need to add to the code if you remove the first loop.  In C and C++, incrementing a pointer increments it in terms of its element size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning, `numPtr` points to the beginning of the set. Then, ***in the first operation, you increment the `numPtr`*** until it points to the end of the set.

When you reach the second iteration, `numPtr` is at `set+sizeof(set)-1`, so you can decrement it to get your set backwards.

Comment: Dohh! Thanks, both answers are good, selected Shitsu's as it went into a bit of detail.

Answer (score 4):

At the time your second loop starts, your `numPtr` points behind the last element of `set`, because you increased it in your first loop.

Without the first loop, it would fail.

Answer (score 0):

**`numPtr`** points to the last element after finishing the first loop.Because in your loop you increment **`numPtr`**.And in your second loop you decrement **`numPtr`**, and after finishing it will point the first element.

> Without the first loop you can reverse the set this way.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

int main(){
    const int SIZE = 8;
    int set[ ] = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40};
    int *numPtr;  
    numPtr = set;
    cout << "\nThe numbers in set backwards are:\n";
    for (int index = 0; index < SIZE ; index++) {
        cout << *(numPtr+SIZE-1-index) << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> **Output:**

```
The numbers in set backwards are:
40 35 30 25 20 15 10 5
```